# How to fire Quartz Cronjob from my unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, tomcat, junit, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am running a Quartz cronjob in my tomcat container, which fires certain schedulers every minute, as shown by the following code:

```
<bean id="cronjobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="job_detail" />
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 */1 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

Now, I intend to write my own unit testing, which needs to fire this Cronjob and then check some consequent output file once the Cronjob is done. In stead of waiting for one minute every time in the unit testing, is it possible to trigger the Cronjob which runs inside my Tomcat, so that the test case won't have to wait for the scheduling interval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that to keep the container running behind is a better idea...